# How can I get lower-case email addresses through an address policy?

Tags: exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011

We use `%g.%s@contoso.com` as our template in an email address policy.

This results in my email address `Oliver.Salzburg@contoso.com`, but I want `oliver.salzburg@contoso.com`. How do I get the address in lower case?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [replace instruction](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/285136) to replace every single upper-case letter with the lower-case counterpart: `%rAa%rBb%rCc%rDd%rEe%rFf%rGg%rHh%rIi%rJj%rKk%rLl%rMm%rNn%rOo%rPp%rQq%rRr%rSs%rTt%rUu%rVv%rWw%rXx%rYy%rZz%g.%s@contoso.com`

Please note that, if you have already applied the previous policy pattern, the lower-case addresses will not replace the previous addresses. You will have to remove those and re-apply the policy.